# Chrome custom tab input data in reverse in form

Tags: android, google-chrome, tabs

I have implemented chrome custom tab, which opens a page that has a form when the user tries to input something it takes input in reverse. Characters enter from left to right and some textboxes do not show any input ?? Same is the case with web view